# Replacing For loop with memcopy, memmove, or std:copy?

Tags: c++

I've got shift function where i an continuously sending it new data points and it will shift my points by an offset of 1. This is to achieve a "graphical shifting" where the points represent points on a graph.

The shifting function is the following:

```
void Chart_Buffer::ShiftData()
{
    for(int index = 0; index < (_channel_Samples - 1); ++index)
    {
      _sample_Points[index].y = _sample_Points[index + 1].y;
    }
  return;
}
```

The problem with this is that it is running through a huge array of up to 800 data points and it does this every time for every new data point added, so i wanted to see if i can optimize this process by shifting all values out by an offset of 1 without running through a for loop. I looked at implementations of memcopy, memmove, and std::copy, but i cant figure out how to use them for my purpose.

Basically, if i have elements 0-799 in the array, i want to shift elements 1-799  by 1 so that i have 0-798 and then just add the new element to the array.

Edit: `_sample_Points` is type `tagPOINT` with the following structure:

```
typedef struct tagPOINT
{
    LONG  x;
    LONG  y;
} POINT, *PPOINT, NEAR *NPPOINT, FAR *LPPOINT;
```

Comment: Instead of shifting everything, why not just maintain a start index? Like a circular buffer, I mean.

Comment: So do you need to shift the whole elements or just the content of `y` only?

Comment: What is the type of `_sample_Points`? Does the stored type hold only 1 member, namely `y`? Or do they have other members?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: _sample_Points is type tagPOINT. It stores an X,Y value. And contents of y only need to be shifted.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I've never done a circular buffer so i wouldnt know where to start.

Comment: The [wikipedia article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) would be a good place.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Thank you, i will take a look at the article.

Comment: I was also able to use `memcpy` to access the structure identifiers for the `POINT *_sample_Points`. I could then reference the memory address and shift these values from their location in the array structure `POINT[_sample_Count]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a firm answer to this without knowing what you are doing with `_sample_Points`. But I believe that I can firmly say that copying every element in the array down one is an expensive approach.

In the best case: **You just need to access the front of the array and add to the back of the array.** If that's the case you're describing a [`queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/).

- To add a new element to the back of a `queue` use: [`push`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/push/)
- To inspect the front element use: [`front`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/front/)
- To "copy everything down one" (just delete the front element) use: [`pop`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/pop/).

Otherwise you'd be in the case where: **You need random access to the array.** If that's the case you can still get potentially better performance from a [`deqeu`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/).

- To add a new element to the back of a `deque` use: [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/push_back/)
- To inspect the front element use: [`front`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/front/)
- To "copy everything down one" (just delete the front element) use: [`pop_front`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/pop_front/)

So if you use a `queue` for your `_sample_Points` `Chart_Buffer::ShiftData` could be replaced by `_sample_Points.pop()`.

If you use a `deque` for your `_sample_Points` `Chart_Buffer::ShiftData` could be replaced by `_sample_Points.pop_front()`.

Comment: I can use a queue. For using pop, you say the front element is deleted. By front element, you mean element at position 0 or n-1?

Comment: @Javia1492 The element at position 0 of the array is `front`. It may be valuable to note that if you try to call `front` on an empty container it's undefined behavior. So just check `_sample_Points.empty()` returns false before using `_sample_Points.front()`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you are looking for a `std::deque`. It is a double ended queue, which means you can pop an element from the back and push on the front.

If what you are looking for is to keep the elements of your array in a certain order, this will help you do just that.

Now if you also want to have them contiguously on memory, then you could do it like this:

```
memmove(array+1, array, sizeof(element)*(array_size-1));
array[0] = new_element;
```

Comment: `realloc`, while succinct, might cause a copy of its own, so I'd  avoid it for this case.

Comment: @CarlNorum just realized he does not need realloc.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without less operations than you are already doing, whether you spell all of them or you call an algorithm. The problem is that the operation is *not* what you described initially, it is not shifting the data, but shifting *part* of the data (only the `y` coordinate) but leaving the other half as it is.

If you don't want to spell out the operation, you can play with the `transform` algorithm in a way similar to the answer by *id256*, but I am not sure whether that is an improvement really, the loop in the question is easier and cleaner than  the `transform`...

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification and yea, i should have specified the type of `_sample_Points` so it is more obvious that i am shifting only the `y` points.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an acceptable amount of refactoring of your code, you could also let go of `tagPOINT` and instead of having one `_sample_Points`, have two arrays, one for the `x` and one for the `y`. Then you can `memmove()` the array of `y`s. Like:

```
LONG _sample_Points_x[DIMENSION];
LONG _sample_Points_y[DIMENSION];

void Chart_Buffer::ShiftData() {
    memmove(_sample_Points_y, _sample_Points_y + 1, (DIMENSION-1) * sizeof _sample_Points_y[0]);
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, i didnt consider changing the structure from tagPOINT to just a pair of arrays. I will try this. Thank you for the response.